# Mount an iso without root access?

Tags: mount, iso

Is it possible for a user without root access to mount an arbitrary iso?
If so how?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this without root access using the [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) module [fuseiso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FuseIso). After fuse and fuseiso have been installed, you can do as a normal user `fuseiso cdimage.iso ~/somedirectory`  to mount it.

You may also need to add your user to the `fuse` group if you get permission errors when trying to use `fuseiso`.

Comment: Also noteworthy is the [kde-service-menu-fuseiso](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/kde-service-menu-fuseiso) to mount them in KDE apps, like Dolphin.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably with `sudo`.  Let's assume that you want everybody in the `cdrom` group able to mount and unmount ISO images.  Make the following addition to the sudoers file using `visudo`:

```
cdrom ALL = /bin/mount -o loop -t iso9660 *.iso /media/*
cdrom ALL = /bin/umount /media/*
```

This should allow anybody in the `cdrom` group to mount a file ending in `.iso` as type `iso9660` on a directory inside the /media folder and also unmount anything in the /media folder.

Comment: good approach, but root access will be needed to use `visudo`

Comment: @phunehehe - As is the case to set up any solution.

Comment: Why not just `sudo su` and be root?

Comment: Can be exploited, for example you could unmount arbitrary filesystems using `umount /media/..`.