# Rip chapters of a DVD to separate files

Tags: debian, dvd, ripping

I have a DVD with cartoons for kids and there are a couple of episodes on every one of them. How can I rip them such that every episode is in a separate file? I think every episode is written as a chapter within one title on the DVD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To extract the .VOB  for  Title 2, Chapter 3

Note that '-chapter 3' and '-chapter 3-' will copy from chapter 3 to the end, and if the chapter number you specify is invalid, the option is ignored, and will therefore copy the full title.

```
# physical DVD
  mplayer dvd://2 -chapter 3-3 -dumpstream -dumpfile ~/3.VOB

# DVD .iso image  
  mplayer dvd://2 -dvd-device "$dvd_iso" -chapter 3-3 -dumpstream -dumpfile ~/3.VOB
```

---

You can use `lsdvd` to list title, chapter, cell, audio, video, etc for a physical DVD.   However, it doesn't seem(?) to have a way to process a `.iso`.   You could [mount a .iso](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/mount-an-iso-without-root-access), if need be.

```
# count Titles, and count Cells per title. 
# eg. ${cell[1]}      is the Count of Cells for the first title
#     ${cell[titles]} is the Count of Cells for the last title

eval $(lsdvd | sed -n 's/Title: \([0-9]\+\), .* Chapters: \([0-9]\+\), Cells: .*/cells[$((10#\1))]=$((10#\2));/p')
titles=${#cells[@]}

title_num=2
from_cell=1
to_cell=${cell[title_num]}
```

---

`dvdxchap`, on the other hand, can process a `.iso`, but it doesn't list title info.   You can, however, specify the title from which you want chapter info.

```
  title_num=2
  from_cell=1
# physical DVD
  to_cell="$(dvdxchap -t $title_num  /dev/dvd | sed -n 's/^CHAPTER\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' | sed -n '$p')"
# DVD .iso image  
  to_cell="$(dvdxchap -t $title_num "$dvd_iso"| sed -n 's/^CHAPTER\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' | sed -n '$p')"
```

---

When you know the title number you want, and know the number of cells, you can dump them in a loop:

```
# physical DVD
  for ((c=$from_cell; c<$to_cell; c++)) ;do
    mplayer dvd://$title_num -chapter $c-$c -dumpstream -dumpfile ~/$c.VOB
  done

# DVD .iso image  
  for ((c=$from_cell; c<$to_cell; c++)) ;do
    mplayer dvd://$title_num -dvd-device "$dvd_iso" -chapter $c-$c -dumpstream -dumpfile ~/$c.VOB
  done
```

Comment: On Ubuntu `dvdxchap` is part of the `ogmtools` package.

Comment: Off by one error here, those for-loops in the last code snippet should have an inclusive `<=$to_cell`. `to_cell` as calculated from `dvdxchap` will return the true total # of chapters (counted starting from 1), numbered the same as `mplayer` understands via `-chapter` flag, so we want to have a final loop where `$c` = `$to_cell`.

Comment: (Missed the comment edit window) # of chapters/cells as calculated by the `lsdvd` `sed` command earlier are the same and also need inclusive for-loop end.

Comment: If you want to encode the output VOB in one go you can output mplayer to a fifo and read in from the fifo with ffmpeg. Using mencoder would probably be cleaner but I'm more familiar with ffmpeg. Made a script to automate most of the process: https://gist.github.com/tobek/eb1af258175ed3627a6b7256859ad4c4

Answer (score 2):

As a script that uses `lsdvd`, Python, and `ffmpeg` to extract the Chapters in a DVD to the current directory (`extract-chapters.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

_genpy () {
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        lsdvd -x -Oy -t "$2" "$1"
    else
        lsdvd -x -Oy "$1"
    fi

    # Process in Python
    cat <<EOF
for t in lsdvd['track']:
    for c in t['chapter']:
        print '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(t['vts'], t['ix'], c['ix'], c['length'])
EOF
}

_genpy "$@" 2> /dev/null | python | {
    dvd_pos=0
    while read line
    do
        dvd_file=$(printf '%02d' $(echo "$line" | cut -f1))
        dvd_tr=$(echo "$line" | cut -f2)
        dvd_cp=$(echo "$line" | cut -f3)
        dvd_len=$(echo "$line" | cut -f4)
        file_name="${dvd_tr}.${dvd_cp}.mkv"
        cat "$1/VIDEO_TS/VTS_${dvd_file}"_*.VOB | ffmpeg -ss "$dvd_pos" -i - -t "$dvd_len" -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis -loglevel error "$file_name"
        echo "Created $file_name"
        dvd_pos=$(echo "$dvd_pos + $dvd_len" | bc)
    done
}
```

Usage:

```
sh extract-chapters.sh PATH_TO_DVD_CONTENTS [TRACK]
```

Comment: For the non-POSIX tools, I chose `lsdvd`, Python, and `ffmpeg` because all of those came in the distribution's OSS repositories; other tools came from third-party repositories (e.g. `dvdbackup`, `makemkv`, etc.).